# Adding timestamp to data frames with different row number in R

Tags: r

```
x1 <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
X1,X2,X3
10,30,07:00
11,31,07:01
12,32,07:02
13,33,07:03
15,35,07:05
16,36,07:06
18,38,07:08
19,39,07:09')

write.csv(x1, file="20120204.csv", row.names=FALSE)
x2 <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
X1,X2
20,40
22,42
23,43
24,44
25,45
26,46')
write.csv(x1, file="20120205.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

I'm attempting to merge this two dataframes. But first I need to add a time stamp X3 in data frame 2 to have this:

```
X1,X2, X3
20,40, 07:00
22,42, 07:01
23,43, 07:02
24,44, 07:03
25,45, 07:04
26,46, 07:05
```

So that later I can merge the two files together by X3

```
final <- merge(X1, X2, by="X2", all=TRUE)
```

I've tried writing this:

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern=".*\\.csv", full.names=TRUE)
first <- TRUE
times <- c("00:00", "23:59")
for (i in fnames) {
    x<-read.csv(i, header=TRUE)
    thisdate <- gsub(".*(20[0-9]{6}).csv", "\\1", i)
    twotimes <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, c("00:00", "23:59")), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
    x$X3 <- seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min")
    outputfile<-paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(i),".csv")
    write.csv(x, file=outputfile)
    first <- FALSE
}
```

But I get this error that says the timestamp has 1440 rows but data x1 and x2 has only 8 and 6, respectively.

How can I "force" the time stamp to be added into the data frame?

Comment: MT32, you just rolled back the edits (indentation, spacing) I made to make this more legible.

Comment: @smci I suspect you were both editing at the same time.

Comment: There are 8 times in your first dataframe, but only 6 rows in your second dataframe. Do you really just want to just take the first 6 times from the first dataframe and add them to the second?

Comment: @Esther yes. But note that this is just one part of a larger problem. The original data set is a list of 1900 files. 
I understand people may suggest other ways but the main point in this question is i need to force that time stamp in dataframe 2.

Comment: for the way you are doing it now, number of rows in data frame should equal the length of the timestamps you are assigning to it

Comment: Right now you're generating 1400 times (one for each minute of a day) but you need a way to select just 6 of those times to add to the second dataframe. Are your files always in pairs, and you always want to select the times from the first file to add to the second? Or do you just want to add a random timestamp so that all your files have the same format?

Comment: @Mankind_008 yes that's what im looking for, but the paste line just wouldnt work with uneven rows...

Comment: @Esther Im looking at creating 1440 times, and paste it in dataframe 2 as column X2. The order of the data relative to the time (column X2) is not important.... So perhaps Im lookin at "add a random timestamp so that all your files have the same format"

Comment: If you don't care what the actual values of the timestamp are, you can just index your sequence `x$X3 <- seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min")[1:nrow(x)]` to fit the size of your dataframe

Comment: @Esther thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Esther for the answer!

Just add the 1:nrow to fit with the size of the dataframe

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern=".*\\.csv", full.names=TRUE)
first <- TRUE
times <- c("00:00", "23:59")
for (i in fnames) {
  x<-read.csv(i, header=TRUE)
thisdate <- gsub(".*(20[0-9]{6}).csv", "\\1", i)
twotimes <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, c("00:00", "23:59")), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
x$X3 <- seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min")[1:nrow(x)]
outputfile<-paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(i),".csv")
write.csv(x, file=outputfile)
first <- FALSE
}
```